# Setup CI Environment Using TFS and Amazon EC2

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Can someone recommend a good approach for setting up a CI environment that would deploy to a multiple websites (QA/PROD) hosted on Amazon's EC2 while using TFS?

Here are the requirements I'm looking to fulfill:

- Have TFS deployed somewhere to track tasks, manage source control, run tests on code check-in and do automatic deployments to a QA environment.
- If everything passes the CI build in TFS, code should be automatically deployed to a QA environment hosted in Amazon EC2.
- After testing, take the same deployment package we used for the QA environment and push it to an identical environment in EC2 which is our production environment.

We are a start-up so we don't need all the of bells and whistles just yet. We have limited resources currently so I am trying to be as minimal as possible while meeting the above requirements.

My first pass at this was to use the free program at Amazon for first-time users to have access to the EC2 cloud for free for 12 months. Then to setup a virtual machine at a low cost (~$20) with a web host to host our TFS environment which would then push to the Amazon cloud.

We also considered using "Visual Studio Online" to do this but it looks like it only deploys to Azure which is a little more than twice the cost to host a website with SQL on than Amazon so we don't want to go that route.

Is this a good approach? I'd appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest TFS vNext build system this should be possible.  You would need to install the AWS command line tools via npm, load your credentials, and then use aws command line to deploy to ec2.

Here is a screen shot of adding an npm task.  Install the aws command line sdk.  Run commands to package and upload your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should install Release Management for Visual Studio 2013. It is easy to install and comes with your MSDN.

http://nakedalm.com/install-release-management-2013/

With it you can create a release pipeline with rollback to deploy your application. You will likely need to add any command line tools that you need to deploy to amazon and it will make sure they get to where they need to be.

http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a licensing cost for Release Management, beyond the standard TFS licensing costs.